# What does it mean for an object to be non-conducting (electrostatics)?

Tags: electrostatics

Does it mean that there can be no flow of charge or does it mean that the substance can not have any excess charge on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object prevents any flow of charge, then it is an insulator. Note that insulators can have excess charge though, for example you could have a uniformly charged sheet of paper with a charge of $+0.5\mu C$.